# Grab data-* attributes from elements and display in <select>

Tags: jquery, each, custom-data-attribute

I have a list of elements, each with a data-producttype attribute, I'm trying to grab the value of each attribute, remove any duplicates, and then create an `<option>` for each data-producttype attribute within a `<select>` element.

I have the following mark up:

```
<ul class="product-grid">
    <li data-producttype="foo">product</li>
    <li data-producttype="bar">product</li>
    <li data-producttype="foo">product</li>
    <li data-producttype="foo">product</li>
    <li data-producttype="foo">product</li>
    <li data-producttype="bar">product</li>
</ul>

<select class="product-types">

</select>
```

With jQuery I've managed to grab one of the data-attributes, so far:

```
$('.product-grid li').each(function(){
    thisdata = $(this).attr('data-producttype');
    $('.product-types').html("<option>" + thisdata + "</option>");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5zz12qpf/

How could i get all the attributes, remove duplicates and create an `<option>` element for each attribute?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array for help removing duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your issues is that `html()` will replace everything so you would only end up with the last option as all others would get replaced.

A simple array to store values will work, if value already exists in array don't create an option

```
var productTypes=[];
$('.product-grid li').each(function(){
   var thisdata = $(this).attr('data-producttype');
    /* only proceed if value doesn't already exist */
    if($.inArray(thisdata, productTypes) === -1){
        productTypes.push(thisdata);
        $('.product-types').append("<option value='" + thisdata + "'>" + thisdata + "</option>");
    }       
 });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zz12qpf/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var products = $.unique($('.product-grid li').map(function(item, index){
   return $(this).attr('data-producttype');
 }));

var productsHtml = "";
$.each(products, function(index, item){
    productsHtml += "<option>" + item + "</option>";
});



$("select.product-types").html(productsHtml);
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zz12qpf/6/